# presentViewController isn't modal in shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make an unwind segue depend on the user approving it in an alert dialog.  However, when I run the code the dialog just quickly appears, disappears, and segues to the other view controller.  I've tried making the alertDialog an instance variable of the class and that doesn't make a difference.  The code below is inside a UIViewController subclass.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var shouldPerformSeque = true

    if identifier == "startOver" {
        let alertDialog = UIAlertController(title: "Warning",
            message: "This will discard all data entered.",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertDialog.addAction(okAction)

        let cancelActionHandler = {
            (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            shouldPerformSeque = false
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel,
            handler: cancelActionHandler)
        alertDialog.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(alertDialog, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    return shouldPerformSeque
}
```

Comment: You can't do this in `shouldPerformSegueWithIndentifier` because the dialog will be presented asynchronously with regard to that method; by the time the action handler closure executes the method has already returned. You need to display the dialog in response to whatever is triggering the segue and then perform the unwind programmatically depending on the user's response

Comment: @Paulw11, that should be an answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I have this working using the provided solution.  However, when I disconnected the button action from the exit segue in the storyboard editor, it removed my seque.  I had to add a disabled and hidden storyboard button connected to the seque to retain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in `shouldPerformSegueWithIndentifier` because the dialog will be presented asynchronously with regard to that method; by the time the action handler closure executes the method has already returned.

You need to display the dialog in response to whatever is triggering the segue and then perform the unwind programmatically depending on the user's response.